# Inject Environment variables into a Jenkins build process with a shell script

Tags: bash, macos, jenkins

**The starting situation**

I have a Jenkins build Project where I'm doing almost everything by calling my build script (`./jenkins.sh`). I'm building a Cordova Project, which is dependent on certain versions of Node and Xcode. I'm running the builds on Macs with the latest MacOS Sierra.

So far I'm setting the environment variables in the Jenkins Build with the EnvInject Plugin(https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin):

[image: Injecting environment variables into Jenkins]

**The Goal**

I want to have the environment variables also set by the build script instead of in the Jenkins Build. This way the environment variables are also in version control and I don't have to touch the Jenkins Build itself.

Basically I need to rebuild the logic of the EnvInject Plugin with bash.

**What I've tried #1**

Within my `jenkins.sh` build script I've set the environment variables with `export`

*jenkins.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash -ve

nodeVersion=7.7.8
xcodeVersion=8.3.1
androidSDKVersion=21.1.2

export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode_${xcodeVersion}.app/Contents/Developer
export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/adt/sdk
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/node/${nodeVersion}/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/adt/sdk/tools:/usr/local/bin/:/Applications/adt/sdk/build-tools/${androidSDKVersion}:$PATH

# print info
echo ""
echo "Building with environment Variables"
echo ""
echo "  DEVELOPER_DIR:  $DEVELOPER_DIR"
echo "  ANDROID_HOME:   $ANDROID_HOME"
echo "  PATH:           $PATH"
echo "  node:           $(node -v)"
echo ""
```

This yields:

```
Building with environment Variables

  DEVELOPER_DIR:  /Applications/Xcode_8.3.1.app/Contents/Developer
  ANDROID_HOME:   /Applications/adt/sdk
  PATH:           /usr/local/Cellar/node/7.7.8/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/adt/sdk/tools:/usr/local/bin/:/Applications/adt/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2:/Users/mles/.fastlane/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
node -v
  node:           v0.10.48
```

`PATH`, `DEVELOPER_DIR`, `ANDROID_HOME` seems to be set correctly, however it is still using the system version of node v0.10.48 instead of v7.7.8 as set in `PATH`.

**What I've tried #2**

I've sourced the variables:

*jenkins.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash -ve

source config.sh

# print info
echo ""
echo "Building with environment Variables"
echo ""
echo "  DEVELOPER_DIR:  $DEVELOPER_DIR"
echo "  ANDROID_HOME:   $ANDROID_HOME"
echo "  PATH:           $PATH"
echo "  node:           $(node -v)"
echo ""
```

*config.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash -ve
# environment variables
nodeVersion=7.7.8
xcodeVersion=8.3.1
androidSDKVersion=21.1.2

export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode_${xcodeVersion}.app/Contents/Developer
export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/adt/sdk
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/node/${nodeVersion}/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/adt/sdk/tools:/usr/local/bin/:/Applications/adt/sdk/build-tools/${androidSDKVersion}:$PATH
```

The result was the same as in `What I've tried #1`: Still using system node v0.10.48 instead of node v7.7.8

**The question**

How can I set the `PATH`, `DEVELOPER_DIR`, `ANDROID_HOME` environment variables properly to be used only within the build script?

@tripleee
Above I'm determining node by calling `node: $(node -v)`. In the build script I'm running gulp which triggers Ionic / Apache Cordova. Do the brackets around `node -v` start a subshell which has it's own environment variables?

@Jacob
We have used nvm before, but we want to have less dependencies. Using nvm requires to install nvm on all build machines. We have a standard of installing node with brew. That's why I'm using `/usr/local/Cellar/node/${nodeVersion}` as path to node.

@Christopher Stobie

env:

```
jenkins@jenkins:~$ env
MANPATH=/Users/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/Users/jenkins/.rvm/man:/Applications/Xcode_7.2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode_7.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man
rvm_bin_path=/Users/jenkins/.rvm/bin
NVM_CD_FLAGS=
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
TMPDIR=/var/folders/t0/h77w7t2s1fx5mdnsp8b5s6y00000gn/T/
SSH_CLIENT=**.**.*.** ***** **
NVM_PATH=/Users/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node
SSH_TTY=/dev/ttys000
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
NVM_DIR=/Users/jenkins/.nvm
rvm_stored_umask=0022
USER=jenkins
_system_type=Darwin
rvm_path=/Users/jenkins/.rvm
rvm_prefix=/Users/jenkins
MAIL=/var/mail/jenkins
PATH=/Users/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin:/Users/jenkins/.fastlane/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/jenkins/.rvm/bin:/Users/jenkins/tools/oclint/bin:/Applications/adt/sdk/tools:/Applications/adt/sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/adt/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4:/Users/jenkins/.rvm/bin
NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://nodejs.org/dist
rvm_loaded_flag=1
PWD=/Users/jenkins
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
_system_arch=x86_64
_system_version=10.12
rvm_version=1.26.10 (latest)
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/jenkins
LS_OPTIONS=--human --color=always
LOGNAME=jenkins
SSH_CONNECTION=**.**.*.** ***** **.**.*.** **
NVM_BIN=/Users/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin
NVM_IOJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://iojs.org/dist
rvm_user_install_flag=1
_system_name=OSX
_=/usr/bin/env
```

alias:

```
jenkins@jenkins:~$ alias
alias l='ls -lAh'
alias rvm-restart='rvm_reload_flag=1 source '\''/Users/jenkins/.rvm/scripts/rvm'\'''
```

Comment: `buildApp()` isn't valid shell syntax for calling a function. Nothing preceding that looks out of the ordinary.

Comment: Are you *executing* the script (rather than sourcing it) and expecting the values to be retained in the current shell after the script exits? Because, no, that won't work. You *cannot* affect the environment of a process from a child process; you have to source the script instead.

Comment: I corrected the buildApp call. This is just to show that after the exports the actual build process starts.

If possible I want to avoid having separate files that I need to source. It would be great to have it all in my shell script (`jenkins.sh`).

Comment: The real question is *How are you calling `node.js`* and how do you determine which version it is?  Show us this part of `jenkins.sh` too.

Comment: Do you have any aliases or other environment variables set that might supersede the path? Can we get the output of env and alias from your jenkins job?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using NVM to switch between node versions? Seems like it would be easier to just do `nvm use`.

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesnt look like an environment variable issue. It looks like a permissions issue. The user executing the script is either:

- not able to read the /usr/local/Cellar/node/7.7.8/bin directory, or
- not able to read the node executable from that directory, or
- not able to execute the node executable from that directory

In order to test, become that user on the machine and execute the node command against the full path:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.7.8/bin/node -v
```

or, if you need to, change the script to avoid using PATH lookups (Im suggesting this for diagnosis only, not as a solution):

```
echo "  node:           $(/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.7.8/bin/node -v)"
```

If you are still at a loss, try this line:

```
echo "  node:           $(sh -c 'echo $PATH'; which node)"
```

Comment: The reason was the script was not able to read the /usr/local/Cellar/node/7.7.8/bin directory. I had node 7.7.8 on my machine installed, but it was node 7.8.0 on the jenkins build machine. Good catch!

Comment: @mles I thought that might be the case. Thats probably a good argument against using the full path to the version. If your brew install is upgraded, you'll need to change your script to match the new version. I'm sure node is symlinked in my brew setup at something like /usr/local/bin/node but I don't know your setup or requirements, so only a suggestion

Comment: we do run brew upgrade, but the idea was to have the build fixed to a node version. it's hardcoded on purpose to node 7.7.8